# ODBC-2028 Error SAP B1

Tags: sapb1

I am trying to add a purchase order by DI API for SAP B1. My code is working on my client but I tried it as an addon on another company that has different data. And it gives the error: "No matching records found(ODBC-2028)". Here is a part of my code:

```
public void createPOrderFor(int id,
                                string itemCode,
                                string itemName,
                                int qty,
                                int satisSip,
                                string cardCode,
                                string cardName,
                                string releaseDate)
    {
        SAPbobsCOM.Documents BO_item;
        BO_item = (SAPbobsCOM.Documents)getCompany().GetBusinessObject(SAPbobsCOM.BoObjectTypes.oPurchaseOrders);
        base.doConnectionInfo();
        server = base.server;
        database = base.database;
        user = base.user;
        pass = base.pass;

        string year = releaseDate.Substring(0, 4);
        string month = releaseDate.Substring(4, 2);
        string day = releaseDate.Substring(6, 2);
        releaseDate = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;

        BO_item.Lines.ItemCode = itemCode;            
        BO_item.Lines.ItemDescription = itemName;         
        BO_item.Lines.Quantity = qty;          
        BO_item.Lines.ShipDate = DateTime.Parse(releaseDate);           
        BO_item.Lines.UserFields.Fields.Item("U_SatisSip").Value = satisSip;           
        BO_item.Lines.Add();
        BO_item.Comments = satisSip + " numaralı satış siparişine istinaden";
        BO_item.CardCode = cardCode;
        BO_item.CardName = cardName;           
        BO_item.NumAtCard = "";
        BO_item.Series = 13;//birincil
        //BO_item.Segment -- it is read only.
        BO_item.TaxDate = DateTime.Now;
        BO_item.DocDate = DateTime.Now;
        BO_item.DocDueDate = DateTime.Parse(releaseDate);
        BO_item.SalesPersonCode = 4;//default Hakan Yılmaz
        BO_item.DocumentsOwner = 4;
        BO_item.DiscountPercent = 0.0;
        BO_item.Address2 = "TURKEY";
        BO_item.Address = "";
        BO_item.TransportationCode = 1;
        BO_item.AgentCode = null;
        BO_item.JournalMemo = "Satınalma siparişleri - " + cardCode;
        BO_item.GroupNumber = 1;//net30 
        BO_item.PaymentMethod = null;
        BO_item.Project = null;
        BO_item.UserFields.Fields.Item("U_SatSip").Value = satisSip;
        var retVal = BO_item.Add();
        int errorCode = 0;
        string errMsg = "";
        if (retVal != 0)
        {
            getCompany().GetLastError(out errorCode, out errMsg);
            SAPbouiCOM.Framework.Application.SBO_Application.StatusBar.SetText("Error: " + errMsg , SAPbouiCOM.BoMessageTime.bmt_Long, SAPbouiCOM.BoStatusBarMessageType.smt_Error);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all remove all null fields. If there are DI Object fields that you cannot provide a value for, you should not set them equal to null.

```
    BO_item.AgentCode = null;
    BO_item.PaymentMethod = null;
    BO_item.Project = null;
```

Just remove them completely. Also instead of `Date.Time.Now` try setting a date in this format: `20180531` for all date fields as a test.

`BO_item.DocDate = "20180531"`

If it returns the same error, attempt to test this in an SAP Business One Demo Database (can be obtained from sap partneredge).

Also, Ensure the User Defined Fields you are trying to set values for exist in your new customer's database

let me know how it works for you so we can continue.

Comment: There are same User Defined Fields in our customer's database but I have figured that there aren't same values for these fields in customer's database  so I made changes on SalesPersonCode, TransportationCode and DocumentsOwner and it is working correctly now.

Comment: I am glad it worked for you. Generally, when the object (if it is a document) returns "No matching records found(ODBC-2028)" it means you are giving it something that cannot be applied. Usually Dates, Nulls or UDF valid values which was your case :)